# Trasnferring Postfix & PostfixAdmin to a new server

Tags: postfix

I have a perfectly working installation of Postfix & PostfixAdmin on a server which I now need to move to a new server. I have thus installed Postfix+Dovecot+SASL and have configured it as on my old server. I have also copied the Postfix files and the DB from the old to the new server. Is copying the Postifx fields and DB enough or should I actually create all accounts by hand?

Answer (score 1):

I ca confirm that copying all files and copying the DB (including adding the "postfix" user) is sufficient. The accounts do NOT need to be created by hand.